# Separar String en grupos de n caracteres java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de separar una variable string en grupos de 4 caracteres para posteriormente pasarlos a ascii y trabajarlos como bytes, el problema es que no consigo separar las variables.
Lo he tratado de hacer así

```
String cad = "Esta es una cadena!";

    ArrayList<String> bloques = new ArrayList<>();
    int aux = 0,cont = 0;
    String trozo = " ";

    do{
        trozo = trozo + cad.charAt(cont);
        if(aux == 4){
            aux = 0;
            System.out.println(trozo.length());  
            bloques.add(trozo);
            trozo = " ";
        }else{
            aux++;
        }
        
        cont++;
    }while(cont < cad.length());

    System.out.println(bloques.toString());
```

Y ni siquiera regresa bloques de 4, los regresa de 6 por los espacios en blanco pero no se de donde salen, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Necesitas partir la cadena sin tomar en cuenta los espacios??

Comment: En una línea `String[] trozos = cad.split( "(?<=\\G.{4})" );`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de [**replaceAll()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) para eliminar los espacios en blanco de la cadena y a si obtener los grupos requeridos

```
//Se reemplaza " " espacio abierto por "" espacio cerrado
    String sinEspacios=cad.replaceAll(" ","");
    
    
        do{
            trozo = trozo + sinEspacios.charAt(cont);
//Los indices se cuenta de 0 asi que en la condicional debe ir 3
            if(aux == 3){
                aux = 0;
                bloques.add(trozo);
                trozo = "";
            }else{
                aux++;
            }
            
            cont++;
        }while(cont < sinEspacios.length());
    
        System.out.println(bloques.toString());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]